# Flutter: How can I store another list in a value of a list - error "type 'UserForPosts' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>of 'iterable'

Tags: flutter, list, dynamic, iterable

I have a list and I want to save another list in a value of this list, but I get the error:

> Flutter: How can I store another list in a value of a list - error "type 'UserForPosts' is not a subtype of type 'Iterableof 'iterable'

Here is my Code:

```
var userInformationSnap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .where('__name__', whereIn: aUserIDOnly)
      .get();

  var userInformationSnapList = userInformationSnap.docs.map((d) =>
      UsersForPosts.fromJson(d.data())).toList();

  for (var i = 0; i < eventsWithoutUserData.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < userInformationSnapList.length; j++) {
      if (eventsWithoutUserData[i].userID == userInformationSnapList[j].UserID) {
        eventsWithoutUserData[i].userInformation.addAll(userInformationSnapList[j]);
      }
    }
  }
```

> Error - "type 'UserForPosts' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable
> dynamic of 'iterable'"

Comment: Change `addAll` to `add`. `addAll` expects the argument to be an `Iterable` while you are sending a single `UserForPosts` object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, like Anis Alibegić said try tor replace **addAll**. with **add.** like this:

```
      for (var i = 0; i < eventsWithoutUserData.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < userInformationSnapList.length; j++) {
      if (eventsWithoutUserData[i].userID == userInformationSnapList[j].UserID) {
        eventsWithoutUserData[i].userInformation.add(userInformationSnapList[j]);
      }
    }
  }

  return eventsWithoutUserData;
```